# Tree structured data prediction

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python

I have tree-structured dataset about parents and childs values. Each data node (except father-node) has some float values. I need to predict childs values.
For being more obvious, I made a picture to show how my data looks like:

[image]

Now it is stored as table with information about parents ids. Fathers do not have any values, but I have information about their ids.

In the picture fathers don't have any values, but mothers and daughters do. This means, that we might know fathers id (and understand, who's father he is), but this node doesn't contain any information to be given to child. Except just being informed about sisters, because of having fathers same id.

I don't know, what kind of influence have mothers values on daughters values, I want to find machine learning / neural network model, that would give me this dependance.

My data is fixed, I don't need to add or delete (maybe only bc of data  cleaning) anything here. But I want to predict float values of child, having ids of parents and mothers float values.

Float values meaning is some measurable parameter per one month. So in the picture you can see information about 3 months.

What machine learning algorithm or neural network approach should I use to predict child values? I was googling tree-structured data approaches, but found only Decision Tree algorithms.

Thanks in advance.